# Ordenar datos según día de la semana en campo enum SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo una tabla en postgres con los siguientes campos:

```
| id  | Dia        |   ToDo
-----------------------------
| 1   | Martes     |  tarea 1
| 2   | Viernes    |  tarea 2
| 3   | Miercoles  |  tarea 3
| 4   | Lunes      |  tarea 4
| 5   | Jueves     |  tarea 5
| 6   | Lunes      |  tarea 6
| 7   | Viernes    |  tarea 7
```

haciendo una consulta, puedo usar la clausula **order by** para obtener la lista ordenada según el id(de forma ascendente y descendente), según el campo ToDo(ascendente y descendente) y finalmente por el día(ascendente y descendente). El problema que veo es q como el campo "Dia" es de tipo **enum** solo puedo ordenarlo alfabeticamente (Jueves, Lunes, Martes, Miercoles, Viernes), pero lo necesito en orden del día(Lunes, Martes, Miercoles, Jueves, Viernes).

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo con consulta?

Estoy consciente que si llevo los días a otra tabla y registro los días en forma ordenada seria mas simple, pero siendo sinceros es un desperdicio ya que simplemente son 7 días de la semana y no habría necesidad de registrar mas(tranquilamente bastaría con un campo enum con los días de la semana )

Answer (score 3):

En los tipos de datos enum el orden de los valores es el orden en que se listaron los valores cuando se creó el tipo. [Documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html#id-1.5.7.15.6)

Ejemplo:

```sql
CREATE TYPE dia as enum ('Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miercoles','Jueves','Viernes');
CREATE TABLE ejemplo_dia (columna dia);
INSERT INTO ejemplo_dia VALUES  ('Viernes'),('Martes'),('Jueves'), ('Lunes'),('Miercoles');
SELECT * FROM ejemplo_dia ORDER BY ejemplo_dia;
  columna  
-----------
 Lunes
 Martes
 Miercoles
 Jueves
 Viernes
(5 rows)
```

Debes crearlo en el orden que requieras, si necesitas saber el orden en que están actualmemte consulta el catálogo:

```sql
SELECT enumsortorder,enumlabel
FROM pg_catalog.pg_enum
WHERE enumtypid = 'dia'::regtype;
 enumsortorder | enumlabel 
---------------+-----------
             1 | Lunes
             2 | Martes
             3 | Miercoles
             4 | Jueves
             5 | Viernes
(5 rows)
```

Ahora si ordernas casteando a texto lo va a ordernar como si fuera texto:

```sql
SELECT * FROM ejemplo_dia ORDER BY ejemplo_dia::text;
  columna  
-----------
 Jueves
 Lunes
 Martes
 Miercoles
 Viernes
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes ordenarlo con un `CASE`

```
SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY (
    CASE Dia
        WHEN 'Lunes' then 1
        WHEN 'Martes' then 2
        WHEN 'Miércoles' then 3
        WHEN 'Jueves' then 4
        WHEN 'Viernes' then 5
        WHEN 'Sábado' then 6
        ELSE 7
    END
 )
```